# ggplot - make custom maps

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to color different counties of Croatia with different colors based on some indicators like the average age, income etc. However, before being able to do that, I was wondering how can I import into R the data on the location of each county.

I couldn't find any preexisting packages containing this data (my apologies if this is untrue, I am new to working with maps in ggplot).

The only thing that I have is a picture which shows the borders of each county, attached below. However, I don't know how to turn this into something ggplot could work with.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the shapefile from https://www.diva-gis.org/gdata by selecting the country as Croatia. Then use the following code

```
library(rgdal)
df <- readOGR(dsn = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\HRV_adm", layer = "HRV_adm1")

#To view the attributes
head(df@data)

#For plotting the map
plot(df["NAME_1"], axes = TRUE)
```

For plotting using `ggplot2` you can use

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
#Plotting Using ggplot2
sf <- st_read(dsn="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\HRV_adm", layer="HRV_adm1")

ggplot(sf) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = NAME_1)) + theme(legend.position = "none")+
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = NAME_1), check_overlap = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded the file and the only difference from your code is that I read in the `shp` file to the `sf` object. However, the shapefile itself is incorrect in one detail. The borders of the capital of Zagreb (on the map that you posted, this is the entity over which the letters "Bje" appear) extend through the pink county around it and split it in two. In reality, the pink county is not split in two by the capital (compare with the map that I posted). Is there any way to go around this?

Comment: Managed to find the proper shapefile here: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/

Comment: For handling shapefile you can use QGIS. If it has answered your question, you can consider accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a shapefile for Croatian counties.

You can start by downloading and unzipping the shapefile [from this page](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html).

You can read a shapefile into R using `readOGR()` in the `rgdal` package.

You can convert the output of `readOGR` to a data frame using `fortify`. Then you'll need to join your other data to that data frame by county name.

Here are the basic steps for plotting a map.

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# change the path here to wherever the .shp file is located
croatia <- readOGR("../../Downloads/gadm36_HRV_shp/gadm36_HRV_1.shp")

croatia_df <- fortify(croatia, region = "NAME_1")

# let's add some fake data called Var
set.seed(1001)
croatia_df <- 
  croatia_df %>% 
  distinct(id) %>% 
  mutate(Var = sample(1:100, 21, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  left_join(croatia_df)

ggplot(croatia_df) + 
  aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = Var) + 
  geom_polygon() +
  geom_path(color="white") +
  coord_map() + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The shapefile is incorrect in the boundaries of the City of Zagreb, so I downloaded the proper shapefile here: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/